# JavaFx how to create chart that only display recent data

Tags: user-interface, javafx, javafx-2, fxml

I have a chart with dynamically added Data. But only want to display for example the last 50 entries.

My x values are incrementing every time by 1.
How do I modify my chart or my series for that?

EDIT 1: And the chart should not display the x- value zero. it should "slide" along with the values. As example you got x values from 0 to 2000. then the graphs x axis should start by 1950 and end with 2000. That you can read all data and stop it from zooming out.

(EDIT 2:
Changing range of the x axis frequently wont work because on the one hand it isn't anywhere near a smooth chart and on the other cost very much performance.)

EDIT 3:
first I had an `int = x` which incremented every milliseconds (or less) and was displayed in the chart. those big numbers where the problem which slowed my performance. I now changed to `double = x` which incremented every milliseconds by 0.001 -> so x was in seconds. and with these small numbers it works smoothly

Thank you

Comment: why do i get a negativ score?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the first element of your `Series`:

```
        series.getData().remove(0);
```

Comment: look at EDIT 1 =)

Comment: @Olgidos try axis.setAutoRanging(true) or manually axis.setRange() after every update

Comment: `if(series.getData().size() > 50){//do what Sergery recomends}`

Comment: mhm this works quit bad ... everytime i set new upper and lower bounds the whole program lags and i wont work anything near smooth

Comment: changing the range more then ever 500 ms slows down the programm extremly and evrything above 100 ms looks unbeliveble awful.

Comment: @Olgidos look at Oracle's Ensemble demo, they had a dynamic chart which worked quite smooth: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/javafx-samples-2158687.html